# localization don't work with ion-tab's title in meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework, internationalization

I am using Meteor + Angular2 + Ionic

Now I need to add i18n to my project. After trying learning Angular official i18n&l10n and angular-translate, I abandoned them for lack of example which makes sense to me.

At last I used:

```
meteor npm install angular-localization --save
```

This package is very simple: each language has a corresponding json file containing all keys and values. The i18n directive just loads the values and sets to element's innerText. I made some modifications and enjoyed using it until I tried to set ion-tab's title.

The source of main function in angular-localization after my modification is:

```
angular
  .module('i18n')
  .directive('i18n', ['$rootScope', '$i18n', function($rootScope, $i18n) {
     return {
        priority: 100,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

           function applyTabTitle(translation) {
              var tabs = element.parent();

              var idx = tabs.children('ion-tab').index(element);
              var a = tabs.children('a').eq(idx);
              a.children('span.tab-title').text(translation);
           }

           function applyLocal() {
               try {
                  var jsn = JSON.parse(attrs.i18n);
                  for (prop in jsn) {
                     var translation = $i18n(jsn[prop]);

                     if (prop == 'tabtitle') {
                        applyTabTitle(translation);
                     } else {
                        element.attr(prop, translation);
                     }
                 }
             } catch (e) {
                 var translation = $i18n(attrs.i18n);
                 element.text(translation);
             }
         }

         applyLocal();

         $rootScope.$on('i18n.language:change', function () {
            applyLocal();
         });
      }
   }
}]);
```

As defined in ionTabNav, The ion-tab will be expanded into something like this

```
<ion-tab icon-on="ios-icon-home" href="#/home"></ion-tab>
<a ng-class="tab-item">
   <i class="icon"></i>
   <span class="tab-title" ng-bind-html="title"></span>
</a>
```

So, I can't just use this (homepage is a language key):

```
<ion-tab data-i18n="homepage" ...>..</ion-tab>
```

because "element.text(translation)" will destroy the expandation. That's why I invented "applyTabTitle" function, then use the following in html:

```
<ion-tab data-i18n='{"tabtitle":"profile"}'>..</ion-tab>
```

But unfortunately, the tab's title remains blank after just redirected to homepage from login page with "$state.go('homepage')", while if I refresh the homepage, the title shows up correctly.

I guess maybe the reason is i18n redirective did not got run prior to ionTab redirective. so I tried to set the priority to 100. but no effect.

Maybe I was on the wrong way from the very beginning. What I want to say is these highly automated frameworks are really hard to customize. the developing process is so bumpy.

Thanks a lot for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem. Not very good but it worked.

Just change applyTabTitle function into the following:

```
function applyTabTitle(translation) {
  var tabs = element.parent();

  var idx = tabs.children('ion-tab').index(element);
  var a = tabs.children('a').eq(idx);
  var txt = applyParams(translation, attrs);
  a.children('span.tab-title').text(txt);
  $rootScope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    a.children('span.tab-title').text(txt);
  });
}
```

The idea is to find a timing after ion-tab has expanded itself, fix the text again.